# How do I get location name or city using latitude & longitudes?

Tags: javascript, geolocation

I'm using the below code, but how to get the city name or the location name from the longitude & latitude?

```
var x=document.getElementById("location");
function getLocation()
{
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition,showError);
    }
    else {
        x.innerHTML="Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
    }
}

function showPosition(position)
{
    x.innerHTML="Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
        "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;  
}
```

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_geocoding

Comment: try the Google Geocoding API https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the Google Maps v3 API to perform reverse geocoding on a latitude and longitude pair. You can find an example of how to do that here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#ReverseGeocoding.

Comment: But location name doesn't appear